# How to remove white space of text in css?

Tags: css, text

How can I align text to the top and left without these empty space?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBMXB.jpg)

```
.text {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

I found out that height I can fix with `line-height: 80%;`

But there's still this left gap

Answer (score 1):

use CSS to achieve this:

```
  html,body{margin:0;}<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
```